# Not all items in Order by are in Select

Tags: t-sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.FoodNumber,
                f.FoodID,
                fn.Name AS FoodName,
                d.[Description],
                substring(n.Note, CHARINDEX(']', n.Note) + 2, 
                                            LEN(n.Note)) AS FoodNote
FROM   Food f
       JOIN FoodName fn
         ON fn.FoodNameID = f.FoodNameID
       JOIN FoodPart fp
         ON fp.FoodID = p.FoodID
       JOIN [Application] a
         ON a.ApplicationID = fn.ApplicationID
       LEFT JOIN [Description] d
         ON d.DescriptionID = ap.DescriptionID
       JOIN Note n
         ON n.NoteID = a.NoteID
       JOIN FoodYear fy
         ON fy.FoodYearID = a.FoodYearID
WHERE  mmy.FoodlId = 33997332
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN substring(n.Note, 1, 1) = 'A' THEN 1
            WHEN substring(n.Note, 1, 1) = 'Y' THEN 2
            WHEN substring(n.Note, 1, 1) = 'D ' THEN 3
          END,
          f.FoodNumber,
          f.FoodID,
          fn.Name,
          d.[description],
          substring(n.Note, CHARINDEX(']', n.Note) + 2, LEN(n.Note))
```

I keep getting an error saying not all the items in the order by are in the select list.

UPDATE

This works but I'm getting dup part numbers listed...I can't add distinct or it will complain that I don't have something in the select list for the order by

```
   select  ap.applicationID,
                    ap.NoteID,
                    f.FoodNumber,
                    n.Note as PartNote,
                    f.FoodID,
                    q.Quantity,
                    fn.Name as FoodName,
                    d.[Description]
    from Food f
                            join FoodName fn on fn.FoodNameID = f.FoodNameID
                            join FoodPart fp on fp.partID = f.FoodID
                            join Quantity q on q.QuantityID = ap.QuantityID
                            join [Application] a on a.ApplicationID = ap.ApplicationID
                            left join [Description] d on d.DescriptionID = ap.DescriptionID
                            join Note n on n.NoteID = ap.NoteID
                            join Note n2 on n2.NoteID = a.NoteID
                            join FoodYear fy on fy.FoodYearID = a.FoodYearID
                            join Model mo on mo.ModelID = fy.ModelID
    where fy.ModelId = @ModelId
    order by
            case when substring(f.FoodNumber, 1, 1) = 'T' then 1
                    when substring(f.FoodNumber, 1, 1) = 'R' then 2
                    when substring(f.FoodNumber, 1, 1) = 'C' then 3
            else
                    substring(f.FoodNumber, 1, 1)
            END,
            f.FoodNumber asc,
            f.FoodID,
            fn.Name ,
            d.[description],
            substring(n.Note, CHARINDEX(']', n.Note) + 2, LEN(n.Note))
```

Comment: The issue is with the  fn.Name which you rename FoodName (You would need to use FoodName in the order by)

Comment: Oh MAN is that so much better!  Wooh!  Also, I'd move the last line of the ORDER BY into the SELECT.  That case statement may need to be moved as well.  Dunno if that's the actual cause; my sql has gotten rusty.

Comment: thanks for your comments...I'm good.   I added another and in my where clause and filtered on another ID in addition to modelId and I'm good to go.  I was not being specific enough...too general on just the modelid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `SUBSTRING(n.Note, 1, 1)` to the `SELECT` list or remove the `DISTINCT`.

You currently are doing `DISTINCT` on `SUBSTRING(n.Note, CHARINDEX(']', n.Note) + 2,  LEN(n.Note)) AS FoodNote` but there can be multiple possible  `SUBSTRING(n.Note, 1, 1)` values that all map to the same value for that.

```
WITH n(Note) AS
(
SELECT '' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT ']'
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(n.Note, CHARINDEX(']', n.Note) + 2, 
                                                LEN(n.Note)) AS FoodNote
      ,SUBSTRING(n.Note, 1, 1) AS SS
FROM n
```

Returns

```
FoodNote SS
-------- ----

         A
         ]
```

You can also use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY MIN(SUBSTRING(n.Note, 1, 1))` so the expression becomes unambiguous in that event and is allowed.

i.e. something like

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT         
        f.FoodNumber,
        f.FoodID,
        fn.Name AS FoodName,
        d.[Description],
        substring(n.Note, CHARINDEX(']', n.Note) + 2, 
                                LEN(n.Note)) AS FoodNote,
        substring(n.Note, 1, 1) AS N1                               
FROM   Food f
       JOIN FoodName fn
         ON fn.FoodNameID = f.FoodNameID
       JOIN FoodPart fp
         ON fp.FoodID = p.FoodID
       JOIN [Application] a
         ON a.ApplicationID = fn.ApplicationID
       LEFT JOIN [Description] d
         ON d.DescriptionID = ap.DescriptionID
       JOIN Note n
         ON n.NoteID = a.NoteID
       JOIN FoodYear fy
         ON fy.FoodYearID = a.FoodYearID
WHERE  mmy.FoodlId = 33997332
)
SELECT FoodNumber,
       FoodID,
       FoodName,
       [Description],
       FoodNote
FROM   CTE
GROUP  BY FoodNumber,
          FoodID,
          FoodName,
          [Description],
          FoodNote
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN MIN(N1) = 'A' THEN 1
            WHEN MIN(N1) = 'Y' THEN 2
            WHEN MIN(N1) = 'D ' THEN 3
          END,
          FoodNumber,
          FoodID,
          FoodName,
          [Description],
          FoodNote
```

Comment: thanks my head is hurting trying to digest this.... with your WITH statement wouldn't you have to do a substring check of note..you have it just (Note)

Comment: for your second idea using Group by, so you mean take what out of the where clause and add what?  And how does group by allow what to be bypassed?

Comment: anyone know why I'd get dups and since I can't use distinct how I can take my working query...the second paste above and rid the dups?  I just get double of every food item..dups.

Comment: isn't it a performance hit with nested selects like this for such a lot going on?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - Not anything over and above the original query. SQL Server just expands these out.

Comment: the query is fine.  I needed to filter on one more in the where clause...I'm good to go.

Comment: thanks all, this is more advanced T-SQL than I'm used to...good to know and I'm learning this CTE stuff...cool.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps add

```
   case when when substring(n.Note, 1, 1) = 'A' then 1
                when substring(n.Note, 1, 1) = 'Y' then 2
                when substring(n.Note, 1, 1) = 'D ' then 3
        END,
```

to your select?

Though I dind't think an order by required something to be in the select.

Also: you don't have a else in the case for if note is not A Y or D.

Comment: RE: "I dind't think an order by required something to be in the select.", you do when `DISTINCT` is used as there may be more than one matching value for a row.